# How to verify a given transaction was sent by a Green Address?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I have run bitcoind. How do I get the funds sent from Green Addresses? If the transaction  is  sent by  Green Addresses, that can be immediately on receipt with zero network confirmations

There are several methods in the list of RPC calls, Is it possible?

Working Example from [Block.io Is Green Transaction?](https://block.io/api/)

List of [RPC calls](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: There's no mention of "green addresses", a concept from 5 years ago that never took off, in the Bitcoin Core code base at all. It has no support for them, never has, never will.

Comment: Did you read out the Block.io Green Transaction Behaviour ?